# Transformar caracteres raros en mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy recogiendo datos almacenados en base de datos, y he visto que hay algunas columnas que tienen caracteres extraños.

**Ejemplo (Extraído desde php)**

> No se est� valorando lo suficiente el deporte y la situaci�n es muy
>   jodida

**Ejemplo (Almacenado en mysql)**

> No se está valorando lo suficiente el deporte y la situación es muy
>   jodida

**Extracto de código**

El objeto de tipo `DatabaseConnection` contiene una instancia de un objeto de tipo mysqli.

```
class DatabaseConnection {

  /**
   * @var mysqli
   **/
  protected $_db;

  /**
   * Database connection construct
   * @param   string  $host
   * @param   string  $user
   * @param   string  $password
   * @param   string  $bd
   * @construct
   **/
  public function __construct( $host = 'localhost', $user = 'root', $password = '***', $bd = 'testing' ){
    $this->_db = new mysqli( $host, $user, $password, $bd );

    if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ){
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }

  /**
   * Do mysql query
   * @param string  $str
   **/
  public function query ( $str ){
    $res = $this->_db->query ( $str );

    return $res;
  }

  /**
   * Close mysql connection
   **/
  public function close(){
    $this->_db->close();
  }

}


$connection = new DatabaseConnection( $config['database']['host'], $config['database']['user'], $config['database']['pass'], $config['database']['db'] );

$query = "select * from news where tipo = 'news' limit 10";

$res = $connection->query( $query );
$arr = [];

if ( $res ){
  while ( $row = $res->fetch_assoc() ){
    $arr[] = $row;
  }

  return $arr;
}
```

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de sustituir estos caracteres por su valor real, en este caso serían vocales con acentos.

Gracias,

Ismael.

Comment: esto puede ser debido a que la base de datos no está codificada en utf-8, y que yo sepa, tal vez me equivoque, si ya están guardados así, deberás modificarlos tu mismo, eso si, recuerda de poner antes el utf-8

Comment: El caso es que en la base de datos si están bien almacenados, es a la hora de extraerlos con php cuándo se muestran así.

Comment: Entonces es tu página que no está en dicha codificación, comprueba que tengas el meta data correcto: `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: No es una página es lo que me muestra el terminal cuándo ejecuto un script muy simple de extracción de datos de base de datos.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un extracto del código, de como sacas esa información de la base de datos?

Comment: @cnbandicoot Acabo de actualizar la pregunta y he añadido el fragmento de extracción de la base de datos.

Comment: @IsmaelMoral has probado cambiandole el charset? `$this->_db->set_charset("utf8")` antes de realizar la consulta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa utf8_encode() para mostrar los strings.
http://php.net/manual/es/function.utf8-encode.php

creo que si lo utilizas en todo el array igual funciona.

```
$arr = utf8_encode($arr);
```

si no, puedes hacer una función que recorra el array y remplace cada string